# ASP.NET Core 2.2 UseSqlServer connection string

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm trying to connect to my sqlserver instance my connection string is this

```
var connectionString = @"Server=192.168.138.227;Database=netcoretest;UserID=test;Password=1234;Trusted_Connection=True;";
services.AddDbContext<CityInfoContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

but it causes an internal server error for my APIs. When i use this

```
services.AddDbContext<CityInfoContext>(o => o.UseInMemoryDatabase());
```

my code seems to work when i use the inmemorydatabase - so I am assuming that my connection string configuration is not correct. I think there is something wrong with my connectionString?

this is my application output

Comment: _my code seems to work_ is not an explanation of your problem. Please tell us what error you receive from the above connectionstring. By the way Trusted_Connection=True and passing a user and a password are not compatible

Comment: youre right. looking at the debug output that was the issue

Comment: it should be User ID not UserID